# What registers do the linux kernel clobber on aarch64 during a syscall

Tags: linux, system-calls, arm64, abi

Every resource I have found about the aarch64 ABI over Linux mentions that `x8` holds the syscall number and that the arguments go in registers `x0` through `x5`. They also note that this registers are caller-saved (including also `x6` and `x7`) when calling subroutines (with `x0` used for the returned value), but they never clarify if the kernel may or may not clobber any register apart from `x0`. Or maybe it isn't even the kernel, like the case with `rcx` and `r11` in x86_64.

The [syscall manpage](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html) doesn't help much:

> Note that these tables don't cover the entire calling convention —some architectures may indiscriminately clobber other registers not listed here.

Well, in that same document `x1` is shown as a 2nd returned value, but in x86_64 `rdx` is also shown as so, and, having a lot of experience with this ISA, I have never seen a syscall return anything in or clobber `rdx`.

Anyway, what I have seen so far (and I have very little experience with ARM/ARM64) is that the only clobbered register is x0.

Comment: If the manpage doesn't state that registers are preserved, then you can't count on registers being preserved.